# Django 1.4 Unknown command: 'runserver'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Something in my python path must have changed because now I cannot run the.

```
python app/manage.py runserver
```

The output I get is

```
Unknown command: 'runserver'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I've looked at my environment's PYTHONPATH and PATH variables, but I can't figure out why its not running.

Comment: this is truly most bizarre. What OS are you using?  I'm tempted to suggest reinstalling django.

Comment: Try creating a new empty Django project or environment+project to localise the breakage?

Comment: what does "python app/manage.py help" output?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question.

- If you've got an error in your settings, manage.py will swallow the exception and report as if the command does not exist.
- This lead me down the path of incorrectly assuming my python path or venv environment was messed up.

If you want to diagnose this issue, run...

```
python app/manage.py help
```

... and it will show the exception. This, of course, was what was recommended by the django shell after it had told me that the command was not found.

This is clearly a bug in Django 1.4. It seems to me, an Exception should be reported regardless of what management command you run.

Comment: you may also use `./manage.py check` to show errors that are otherwise suppressed.

Comment: For Django 1.4 `./manage.py check` won't work. You should use `./manage.py validate` instead. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#validate

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the `manager.py` code and `django.core.management` I can come up with some suggestions.

First, check if the file `<some_path>/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py` exists.

Second, run:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

If the aforementioned `<some_path>` is not in this list than you must set the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Third, (and that's the longest of all shots) if you have changed the `DEFAULT_PORT` of `runserver`, try changing it back to `8000`.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with OP. I met the same problem, and it turned out to be an error in `settings.py`:
In settings.py I use `os.environ[something]` and those environment variables are loaded in apache start script. If I run `manage.py` from the command line, it doesn't know what is `os.environ[something]` thus error occurs.

So for anyone here searching for solution, suggestion is to check **circumstance difference** between running django project and pure manage.py, maybe you'll find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I will add my answer to the same problem I had. This was unrelated from Django version, but in an old instance of my project I was providing my own Django copy and not installing from pip. Later I decided to use Pip installed Django.

When I pulled the changes on the server, my repo's copy of Django files were deleted but not the .pyc files. `manage.py` would still import the old .pyc files making the imports break half way and the error was the same "Unknown command: runserver".

Naturally, fully deleting the folder with the .pyc files fixed the problem.