# Unknown command: 'runserver'

Tags: python, django

Out of the blue, I can not longer use `manage.py` "command" (runserver, shell, syndb).  Here's the error I get;

```
(pinax) C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax\catalog>python manage.py runserver
Unknown command: 'runserver'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

(pinax) C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax\catalog>python manage.py help
Usage: manage.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                    "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                    used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                    A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                    "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Print traceback on exception
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 28, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 352,
 in execute_from_command_line

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 295,
 in execute

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 242,
 in main_help_text

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 128,
 in get_commands

KeyError: 'startproject'

(pinax) C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax\catalog>
```

I am running a pinax project in a virtual environment.  So when I go this error I checked by PYTHONPATH in windows which was gone.  Set that up again, still no change.  I am still new to python but it appears forsome reason it is looking for "`__init__`"  in the build file, instead of "`site-packages\django`".  Any thoughts as to the source of my problem.

Comment: Try to use this python manage.py runserver --settings=settings

Comment: The `build` directory is probably part of a `setup.py` distutils run.  If so, you may be able to delete it.  Please add the contents of the `PYTHONPATH` to your question as well as your directory layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Catherine, but I got the same result.

Comment: Austin, my PYTHONPATH is:                      C:\python27;c:\python27\scripts;c:\python27\lib;C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax;C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax\Lib;C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax\Scripts;C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax\catalog;C:\Python27\Projects\Catalog\pinax\Lib\site-packages\django

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django 1.4 Unknown command: 'runserver'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885299/django-1-4-unknown-command-runserver)